# Is there a way to get event signature using web3.js?

Tags: web3js

I have [abi](/questions/tagged/abi) of a contract and I am using it to construct `Contract` instance of [web3js](/questions/tagged/web3js):

```js
const pairContract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI_JSON);
```

Reading the documentation, I see that there is a [`contract.events`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events) property, which should give me access to computed signature, e.g.

```js
pairContract.events;

{
  Sync: [Function: bound ],
  '0x1c411e9a96e071241c2f21f7726b17ae89e3cab4c78be50e062b03a9fffbbad1': [Function: bound ],
}
```

I want to get signature for the `Sync` event. How do I do this?

To be clear, I know that I can calculate the signature myself if I know the event name and parameter names, e.g.

```js
web3.utils.sha3('Sync(uint112,uint112)')
```

The question is only if [web3js](/questions/tagged/web3js) provides a convenient way to get event signature just by knowing the event name.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `options` holds computed values:

```js
pairyContract.options.jsonInterface.find((token) => {
  return token.type === 'event' && token.name === 'Sync';
});
```

Result:

```js
{
  anonymous: false,
  inputs: [
    {
      indexed: false,
      internalType: 'uint112',
      name: 'reserve0',
      type: 'uint112'
    },
    {
      indexed: false,
      internalType: 'uint112',
      name: 'reserve1',
      type: 'uint112'
    }
  ],
  name: 'Sync',
  type: 'event',
  constant: undefined,
  payable: undefined,
  signature: '0x1c411e9a96e071241c2f21f7726b17ae89e3cab4c78be50e062b03a9fffbbad1'
}
```